# Multiple UpdateProgress controls on a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a page with several `UpdatePanel` controls, each with a related `UpdateProgress`. When the asynchronous requests are posted back, only the first `UpdateProgress` control is displayed. The other requests complete successfully, but the `UpdateProgress` is not shown.

**How can I get all the update panels on the page to show properly?**

Here is a example that shows the problem (sorry it's a bit long):

#### aspx file:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="true" Interval="1000" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
  <ProgressTemplate>Updating...</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer2" runat="server" OnTick="Timer2_Tick" Enabled="true" Interval="2000" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2">
  <ProgressTemplate>Updating...</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

#### codebehind:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}

protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Timer2.Enabled = false;
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Does `UpdatePanel2` work if you don't run the timer in `UpdatePanel1`? Also, if you set `UpdateMode="Always"`, does that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that everything works as expected if I put the `UpdateProgress` **before** the corresponding `UpdatePanel`...

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
  <ProgressTemplate>Updating...</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="true" Interval="1000" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```